# Left click isn't digging in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After updating to the new version I can no longer dig when I click and hold left Mouse button. I have made sure I am in creative mod. When I click my left mouse button I just get a `\`.

Comment: Where do you get this `\`? Go into **Options** and check your key bindings.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I'd check is to make sure your controls are set correctly.

1. Open Minecraft and go to Options | Controls
2. Two things to check on this page:

   - Is Attack set to 'Button 1'?
   - Is Command set to 'SLASH'?

If either of these controls are mapped incorrectly, make any necessary changes and load a new world to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot destroy blocks anymore with a sword, if you are equipping a sword that might be the problem.

Comment: A sword would still work, in this instance, due to creative mode.